# If $B$ is a cover of $A$, then do we say that $C$ is a subcover of $B$, or of $A$?

Tags: general-topology, terminology

My textbook variously says both "subcover of $A$" and "subcover of $B$" to refer to a subcollection $C$ of the collection $B$ (that covers $A$); is this usage standard and is it not potentially confusing?

Example sentence: "Consider the open cover $B$ of $A$. By Lemma 2, $B$ has a finite subcover $C$ of $A$." I appreciate that it is useful to be able to specify the "base" set $A$, but isn't $C$ a subcover of $B$, instead of a subcover of $A$?

Another question: are these three sentences equivalent ($A$ and $B$ are sets)?

> 1. $B$ covers $A$.
> 2. $B$ contains $A$.
> 3. $A$ is a subset of $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally call it a subcover of the cover, but the important question is whether the message gets across.

To answer your second question: no, except sometimes for the second and third.

1. $B$ covers $A$, in a topological context, means that $A \subseteq \bigcup B$ (there is a very different meaning in lattice theory).
2. $B$ contains $A$ either means $A \subseteq B$ or $A \in B$, depending on context.

Comment: Thanks. Oh actually, on-reading, I see why 1. and 2. aren't equivalent: in 1., the B is merely a collection of sets, as opposed to a union of sets, so while the union of B's members contain A, B itself cannot contain A *unless* A happens to coincide with one of those members. I would modify what you wrote to  $A \subseteq \bigcup_i B_i$, where $B=\{B_i\}$, otherwise it does really look like B contains A (instead of covers A).

Comment: @Ryan: $\bigcup B$ is standard notation in set theory (hence also topology). By definition, $(\forall x)(x\in \bigcup B \iff (\exists S\in B)(x\in S))$. $\bigcup B$ should be thought of as "the union of all the elements of $B$".

Comment: Thanks. I didn't mean that your notation wasn't standard, I was referring to your answer in the context of my particular question.